# SQL - query with group by and details at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have sql query like this:

```
SELECT sum(amount) AS sum, incomes_category_assigned_to_users.name AS category_name
        FROM incomes 
        INNER JOIN incomes_category_assigned_to_users on incomes.income_category_assigned_to_user_id = incomes_category_assigned_to_users.id 
        WHERE (incomes.user_id = :user_id AND date_of_income >= :first_date AND date_of_income <= :second_date)
        GROUP BY incomes.income_category_assigned_to_user_id 
        ORDER BY sum DESC;
```

The result is the user incomes grouped by the category - displayed as an array.

I would like to add subquery - get these incomes, not grouped, so that the user can expand the field in array and see it in detail.

Thanks for help

Comment: Another option might be to use `WITH ROLLUP` to get the high-level sums (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html). So you select the individual rows (not the grouped sums), and then using `WITH ROLLUP` it will return the sums too. Then you just need to identify these rows (i.e. if incomes.name is null) and output them accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not support arrays.  One method is to put the values into a string:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS sum,
       GROUP_CONCAT(amount) as amounts,
       icau.name AS category_name
FROM incomes i JOIN
     incomes_category_assigned_to_users icau
     ON i.income_category_assigned_to_user_id = icau.id 
WHERE i.user_id = :user_id AND
      date_of_income >= :first_date AND
      date_of_income <= :second_date
GROUP BY icau.name
ORDER BY sum DESC;
```

Note the changes I made to the query:

- The tables have reasonable table aliases.  They make the query easier to write and to read.
- No parentheses are needed in a `WHERE` clause that just uses `AND`.
- The `GROUP BY` keys are now consistent with the unaggregated `SELECT` columns.